# Few rules in my htaccess file is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing some issues with my htaccess. Below is htaccess file I am using. The 301 redirect is working fine but redirects for books isnt working at all.

Another rule at bottom of file `^books.php /books/ [R=301,L]` is also working. I am just wondering what is wrong with other rules.

Website is www.gatecounsellor.com

http://www.gatecounsellor.com/books.php is getting redirected according to rule but not this, http://www.gatecounsellor.com/books/aerospace-engineering-ae/

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gatecounsellor\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gatecounsellor.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^books/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$     /books/display_book_detail.php?branch=$1&subject=$2&title=$3&isbn_13=$4 [NC,L]    # Handle   product requests
RewriteRule ^books/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /books/display_subject_books.php?branch=$1&subject=$2 [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule ^books/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /books/display_branch_subjects.php?branch=$1   [NC,L]    # Handle product requests

RewriteRule ^books.php /books/ [R=301,L]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Any clues what could be wrong in other rules?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion, look into creating a routing structure in your app then you only need one rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]` you can then parse the route with `explode('/',$_GET['route']);` what your doing will eventually become unmaintainable.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and is there any other .htaccess in `/books/` directory as well?

Comment: Yea this approach will be a issue later but for now major thing for us  is to make it work.

@anubhava , there is no other .htaccess file anywhere else. I had checked it.

Comment: Is this .htaccess placed in `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Yea its in document root.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to enabling of `MultiViews`:

Place this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

**UPDATE:** Move these 2 rules in `/books/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /books/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ display_book_detail.php?branch=$1&subject=$2&title=$3&isbn_13=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ display_subject_books.php?branch=$1&subject=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ display_branch_subjects.php?branch=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Just tried this but its not working. I am not getting any clue of this issue.

Comment: Do you have more rule OR everything as you have shown in the question? Also which URL are you using to test it. Is this: `http://www.gatecounsellor.com/books/aerospace-engineering-ae` not working?